# How to deny MSVC from including headers by itself

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, cross-platform

I wrote a small C++ code and compiled it in MSVS 2013. It compiled fine. However, I tried to compile it on Ubuntu using GCC and it gave an error that I am using `std::abs` which is not exist. Then I solved the problem by including `cmath`.

Why MSVS did not complain? Does it include some headers by itself. If yes, how can I deny MSVS from including whatever it wants so this kind of non cross-platform code disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it include some headers by itself

While it could do that depending on the project settings, the problem probably is not a direct include. What MSVC (and GCC too) do too is to include header A in header B, because A has some part which is needed in B internally. As side effect, of course you'll get other symbols from header B too ...

> If yes, how can I deny MSVS from including whatever it wants

Without rewriting the whole header tree, you can't. That (and many other compiler-specific things) is a good reason to compile with both VS and GCC, always or at least in regular intervals, instead of writing the whole program with one compiler only first. (*especially* if VS is your main tool).